# Spring Boot: Is it possible to consume @RequestParam's as json?

Tags: java, json, spring

I have following rest endpoint in spring boot application:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/sign-in")
    public Client signIn(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Client client = authService.signIn(username, password);
        return client;
    }
```

I want accept data as application/json.

Is it possible to do this WITHOUT creating class for this like this?:

```
public class LoginModel {
   private String username;
   private String password;
   ...
}
```

Also, without argument of type Map in **signIn** method

I need to accept application/json with this signature:

```
public Client signIn(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't think it's possible.

You need to create the intermediary `Login` object.

`@RequestParam` mandates you have a request param.